# Apache PHP7 Mysql5 on Ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: php

I tried to install a small Webserver on Ubuntu 16.04.1.

I followed a few instructions on the internet where they explained how to set up Apache and the other needed software (like php 7, mysql, e.g.).
I followed the tutorial and when trying to open the `test.php` file (http://192.168.bla.bla/test.php [bla.bla is my local ip]) nothing happened. The page does nothing. No error. No output.

This is the instruction I followed (the others I just used to check if they have other ideas):
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-apache2-with-php-7-support-in-ubuntu-16-04-server.html

Any ideas how I can check what is wrong / what is missing?

Thanks a lot!!!

**UPDATE:** I checked a few settings but I still don't have a solution.

apache2 is available and loaded ("sudo systemctl status apache2")

php7.0 is installed and enabled (Verify: "a2query -m php7.0" ; Load: "sudo a2enmod php7.0")

But still no success.

**update 2**

Now I followed these instructions ( howtoforge.com/tutorial/apache-with-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-16-04/ ) but I think I made it worse..

Can't restart apache:

Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
And when loading the test.php file I don't get a blank page, I get an error now (what is logical). :(

Comment: I'm thinking of doing similar using `sudo apt-get install lamp-server*` as described here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42480/how-to-turn-your-home-ubuntu-pc-into-a-lamp-web-server/

Comment: perhaps your missing the `libapache2-mod-php7.0` module, Install `sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.0`, then make sure the `test,php` is located here `/var/www/html/`

Comment: When using this new method make sure to remove the other install

Comment: Thanks. I think I already installed libapache2-mod-php7.0. And i also made sure that the test.php file is in the right folder. php5 is not installed, i checked that too. Any other ideas?